# applying function to sections of array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, loops

Let's say I have an array in MATLAB called temp with:

```
   40.2000
   40.2000
   40.2000
   39.2000
   39.2000
   39.2000
   38.5000
   38.5000
   38.5000
   38.5000
   38.5000
   39.4000
   42.7000
   42.7000
   42.7000
   42.7000
   42.7000
   44.1000
   44.1000
   44.1000
```

I would like to apply some function only on sections of this array at a time that has the same values, so apply function to elements 1:3, then apply it to 4:6, etc...

What is the easiest way for me to do this?

Comment: It's important to know what the specific function is. In addition to Suever's great answer, a faster approach may be possible depending on what you want to do with each group of equal values. Also, you should specify what happens with data `[3 3 2 2 2 3 3 4 4]` for example. Should values `3` form one or two groups?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, the general function approach that Suever providing was what I was looking for. Thanks for your efforts though! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to perform an operation on the groups of unique values. First we can use `unique` to perform the grouping for us into unique values and the result is an array of indices the size of your input where each element contains an index which indicates which unique group it belongs to. We can then feed this to `accumarray` which will accept an array of values and perform the desired option on this array. In the example below, I'm assuming that you have a function named `your_operation.m` that takes an array as input and yields a scalar.

```
[~, ~, b] = unique(data, 'stable');

% Now perform your operation on each group
results = accumarray(b, data, [], @(x)your_operation(x));
```

If you need to return an array from your function you'll want to wrap the call to `your_operation` in `{}` to make it a cell array

```
results = accumarray(b, data, [], @(x){your_operation(x)});
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for that detailed answer! It was very helpful and what I was looking for :) happy new year.